# CrossPlatform Google Analytics with MvvmCross & Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-analytics, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing crossplatform application with Xamarin + MvvmCross and wondering is there any cross-platform implementation of Google Analytics (suitable for Portable Class Libs)?

Or should I create an abstraction of analytics service and add native implementation for each platform?

Thank you for any suggests.

Comment: A Flurry bindings there is already here https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/FlurryAnalytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suitable for Portable Class Libs?

No, the analytics providers all provide native libraries.

> Should I create an abstraction of analytics service and add native implementation for each platform?

Yes - this is the way I'd go.

I've previously done this for Flurry Analytics - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-flurry-analytics-from-monotouch.html - would be great to see someone share the same for other analytics providers

Comment: thank you for the link and your response. It is quite clear now where to go.